# Angular Material Menu per mat-row on click to the row

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have this Material table:

```
<table mat-table
       [dataSource]="dataSource">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell
        *matHeaderCellDef>ID</th>
    <td mat-cell
        *matCellDef="let report"
        [innerText]="report.id"></td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['id']"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['id'];"></tr>

</table>
```

I'm trying to implement a `[matMenuTrigger]` for `mat-row`. Every row will have its own `mat-menu` with the properties of `report`.

The problem is I can do

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['id']" [matMenuTriggerFor]="rowMenu"></tr>
```

however I do not have a reference to `reportMenu` since I can only define `reportMenu` within some `matColumnDef`:

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell
        *matHeaderCellDef>ID</th>
    <td mat-cell
        *matCellDef="let report"
        [innerText]="report.id"></td>

    <mat-menu #reportMenu="matMenu">
        {{ report.name }}
    </mat-menu>

  </ng-container>
```

and when I have a reference to `mat-row` I do not have a reference to the `report` itself. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your menu outside of your table. Don't worry, it will work.

Then, [follow the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview#passing-in-data-to-a-menu) to give data to your menu.

```html
<mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu">
  <ng-template matMenuContent let-name="name">
    <button mat-menu-item>Settings</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Log off {{name}}</button>
  </ng-template>
</mat-menu>

<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu" [matMenuTriggerData]="{name: 'Sally'}">
  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>

<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu" [matMenuTriggerData]="{name: 'Bob'}">
  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: Did you read the question? It's not that I'm worried it'll not work, I do not have a reference to `report`, which is row data, which is only available within column.

Comment: Did you read the documentation ? I gave you a way to send your row data to your menu.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't think it could be necessary to mention that I'm not using lazy loading, which I thought why the method in documentation didn't work. I found a walkaround, do you think you can update the answer and replace the link with the content so that I can answer it?

Comment: Lazy loading is not an issue, you can use it without changing anything in your app. And sure, it's done

Comment: Lazy rendering works perfectly. Just place menu template out of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `ng-container matColumnDef` everything else but mat-cell elements will be ignored. It's by design.

Possibly [lazy rendered](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview#lazy-rendering) menu is solution? You can easily pass row data to `matMenuContent` to render different menu per row.